# Is this using PDO and prepared statements correctly for a secure login?

Tags: php, security, authentication

Once again looking for some help with PHP security and a login system. Wondering if i did this correctly here. If i wasn't specific enough anywhere please ask, Any help is greatly appreciated. I am trying to create a secure login system, just for purposes of learning. here is the code:

```
require("constants.php");
$DBH = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

function createSalt() {
    $length = mt_rand(64, 128);
    $salt = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $salt .= chr(mt_rand(33, 255));
    }
    return $salt;
}
//Salt function created by ircmaxell

function registerNewUser() {
    //Check to see if     Username Is In Use//
    $q = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?"); 
    $username = filter_var($username, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $data = array($username);
    $q->execute($data);
    $row = $q->fetch();

    if ($row === false) { 
        //If Username Is Not Already In Use Insert Data//
        $hash = hash('sha256', $pass);
        $salt = createSalt();
        $hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash . $pass);  //UPDATED
        $data = array($username, $hash, $salt);
        $qInsert = $DBH->prepare(
            "INSERT INTO users (username, password, salt) values (?, ?, ?)"
        );
        $qInsert->execute($data); //Inserts User Data Into Table//  
    }
}
```

Comment: Searching PHP.net, I don't find a function named "canonicalize()"  Is this a user defined function that's not included in the code?

Comment: Also, the bind_param() is called with "i" as the variable, yet "i" isn't defined in your prepared statement.  You can just pass a the username variable as a single member array to the execute statement and skip the bind_param().

Comment: yeah i see that canonicalize() is not a function, i thought i had read that it was a function. Guess not. thanks, As for the variable, thanks for that too. Ill edit it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ok its been updated to fix the variable issue. Although, I am relatively new to PHP, so does that look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks good so far. I have three suggestions, though:

1. Choose a longer salt
2. Don't store salt and password digest separately
3. If your database connection is not to `localhost` use a different database connector: PDO doesn't (yet) support SSL connections

**EDIT:** Also, validate the input a client provides as a "username". But since your code sample is just an excerpt I guess you're doing that.

**EDIT #2:** When I said, "don't store salt and password separately" I meant incorporating the salt into the stored password hash. Since the hash algorithm of your choice produces quite a long string (64 character) composed of [0-9a-f] you might want to contemplate generating a salt of random length (credits to ircmaxell here) and either concatenate that to the beginning or end of the password hash. So you'll end up storing variable length values (96 - 128 characters) worth of meaninglessness (to outsiders):

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $pass);
$salt = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand(0, 1337)), mt_rand(0, 31), 32);
$hash = $salt . hash('sha256', $salt . $hash . $pass);
```

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the comment. I was not aware that PDO did not support SSL. Any suggestions on that? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Also, I am worried about performance. I don't know too much here, but am i possibly using too many variables?

Comment: As for prepared statement support (which is a *Good Thing*), I use PHP's mysqli extension. As for the variables: I'm personally a fan of readable code. So: no. It's better to be able to *read* code instead of having to decipher it, because you're accessing `$_POST['foo'][0]` for the 10th time.

Comment: +1 for longer salt.  I personally like using a variable length (chosen at random) between 64 and 128 characters...

Comment: @ircmaxell Thanks. That's also very confusing for people trying to brute force your hashes if $%&# has hit the fan and they got a hold of your MySQL dumps...

Comment: Well, if you're worried about that, you can store a second salt outside of the database.  That way even if they get MySQL, they won't have enough info to even brute force a usable password (assuming a strong second salt).  They'd need both (I've used Apache-set environmental variables for this before.  So even if the user gets all of the PHP code, they won't get the salt)...

Comment: Its been updated, besides the PDO connection. I still need to fix that. How's everything look thus far?

Comment: @mcbeav It looks alright. I have an addition, though. Please see my second edit.

Comment: Thanks, I will change that, but I have a question then; How am I going to compare the strings when someone attempts to login?

Comment: and as for changing from PDO i could just basically use: <code>$DBH = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);</code> and change the PDO fetch?

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion.  Add the password into the salting hash run:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $pass);
$salt = createSalt();
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash . $pass);
```

The reason is to avoid collisions (albeit with `SHA-256` that's pretty unlikely).  Let's say there is a string `foo` that collides with your password `bar` when run through `sha256`...  `$hash` from the first round would be identical, so the second hash round will also produce identical results:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', 'foo'); // "test" for example
$hash = hash('sha256', 'bar'); // "test" since it's a collision

$newHash = hash('sha256', $salt . $hash); //The same for both foo and bar!
```

Whereas if you re-introduce the the password in the second round, it won't directly collide since the string is different for each hash round...

**Edit:** As far as salting, I'd recommend something like this (cross-platform):

```
function createSalt() {
    $length = mt_rand(64, 128);
    $salt = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $salt .= chr(mt_rand(33, 255));
    }
    return $salt;
}
```

It uses characters outside the normal range (much higher), but excludes the common control and whitespace characters that might be stripped by the database (or trimmed out).  Note that it's returning a valid ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) string.  It's not a valid UTF-8 string.  So make sure the character set of the column is good, or in the worst case change `255` to `127` in the code above (but this greatly reduces the strength of the salt)...

Comment: Thanks a ton for the salt function. I really appreciate all of the help. The suggestion is great too! Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: +1 for you too. Although the chances of producing collisions still exist, getting hit by lightning while cashing in your lottery ticket you found while taking a detour on a road never travelled before, are higher.

Comment: @goreSplatter: Absolutely, assuming we're talking about the implementation detail of `sha-256`.  If it was `md5`, then it's only like getting hit by lightning once in your lifetime...

Comment: That's what I meant. In my answer below, I only abstained from saying "Don't use MD5, it's not collision free" because it was only used for generating the salt.