# Please critique this PHP login script

Tags: php, security, login-script

A site I developed was recently compromised, most likely by a brute force or Rainbow Table attack. The original log-in script did not have a SALT, passwords were stored in MD5.

Below is an updated script, complete with SALT and IP address banning. In addition, it will send a Mayday email and SMS and disable the account should the same IP address or account attempt 4 failed log-ins. Please look it over and let me know what could be improved, what is missing, and what is just plain strange.

```
<?php
    //Start session
    session_start();
    //Include DB config
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/pdo_conn.inc.php';

    //Error message array
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;

    //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
    function clean($str) {
        $str = @trim($str);
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $str = stripslashes($str);
        }
        return $str;
    }

    //Define a SALT, the one here is for demo
    define('SALT', '63Yf5QNA');

    //Sanitize the POST values
    $login = clean($_POST['login']);
    $password = clean($_POST['password']);
    //Encrypt password
    $encryptedPassword = md5(SALT . $password);
    //Input Validations
    //Obtain IP address and check for past failed attempts
    $ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $checkIPBan = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_ban WHERE ipAddr = ? OR login = ?");
    $checkIPBan->execute(array($ip_address, $login));
    $numAttempts = $checkIPBan->fetchColumn();
    //If there are 4 failed attempts, send back to login and temporarily ban IP address
    if ($numAttempts == 1) {
        $getTotalAttempts = $db->prepare("SELECT attempts FROM ip_ban WHERE ipAddr = ? OR login = ?");
        $getTotalAttempts->execute(array($ip_address, $login));
        $totalAttempts = $getTotalAttempts->fetch();
        $totalAttempts = $totalAttempts['attempts'];
        if ($totalAttempts >= 4) {
            //Send Mayday SMS
            $to = "admin@somewhere.com";
            $subject = "Banned Account - $login";
            $mailheaders = 'From: noreply@somewhere.com' . "\r\n";
            $mailheaders .= 'Reply-To: noreply@somewhere.com' . "\r\n";
            $mailheaders .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $mailheaders .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $msg = "<p>IP Address - " . $ip_address . ", Username - " . $login . "</p>";
            mail($to, $subject, $msg, $mailheaders);
            $setAccountBan = $db->query("UPDATE ip_ban SET isBanned = 1 WHERE ipAddr = '$ip_address'");
            $setAccountBan->execute();
            $errmsg_arr[] = 'Too Many Login Attempts';
            $errflag = true;    
        }
    }
    if($login == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Login ID missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }

    //If there are input validations, redirect back to the login form
    if($errflag) {
        $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
        session_write_close();
        header('Location: http://somewhere.com/login.php');
        exit();
    }

    //Query database
    $loginSQL = $db->prepare("SELECT password FROM user_control WHERE username = ?");
    $loginSQL->execute(array($login));
    $loginResult = $loginSQL->fetch();

    //Compare passwords
    if($loginResult['password'] == $encryptedPassword) {
        //Login Successful
        session_regenerate_id();
        //Collect details about user and assign session details
        $getMemDetails = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_control WHERE username = ?");
        $getMemDetails->execute(array($login));
        $member = $getMemDetails->fetch();
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['user_id'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_USERNAME'] = $member['username'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_FIRST_NAME'] = $member['name_f'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_NAME'] = $member['name_l'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_STATUS'] = $member['status'];
        $_SESSION['SESS_LEVEL'] = $member['level'];
        //Get Last Login
        $_SESSION['SESS_LAST_LOGIN'] = $member['lastLogin'];
        //Set Last Login info
        $updateLog = $db->prepare("UPDATE user_control SET lastLogin = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR), ip_addr = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
        $updateLog->execute(array($ip_address, $member['user_id']));
        session_write_close();
        //If there are past failed log-in attempts, delete old entries
        if ($numAttempts > 0) {
            //Past failed log-ins from this IP address. Delete old entries
            $deleteIPBan = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM ip_ban WHERE ipAddr = ?");
            $deleteIPBan->execute(array($ip_address));
        }
        if ($member['level'] != "3" || $member['status'] == "Suspended") {
            header("location: http://somewhere.com");
        } else {
            header('Location: http://somewhere.com');
        }
        exit();
    } else {
        //Login failed. Add IP address and other details to ban table
        if ($numAttempts < 1) {
        //Add a new entry to IP Ban table
        $addBanEntry = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO ip_ban (ipAddr, login, attempts) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        $addBanEntry->execute(array($ip_address, $login, 1));
        } else {
            //increment Attempts count 
            $updateBanEntry = $db->prepare("UPDATE ip_ban SET ipAddr = ?, login = ?, attempts = attempts+1 WHERE ipAddr = ? OR login = ?");
            $updateBanEntry->execute(array($ip_address, $login, $ip_address, $login));
        }
        header('Location: http://somewhere.com/login.php');
        exit();
    }
?>
```

**EDIT**

Okay, here is my attempt at a random Salt. First, create the salt to be inserted into the table:

```
define('SALT_LENGTH', 15);
function createSalt()
{
    $key = '!@#$%^&*()_+=-{}][;";/?<>.,';
    $salt = substr(hash('sha512',uniqid(rand(), true).$key.microtime()), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    return $salt;
}
$salt = createSalt()
//More prep for entering into table...
```

Then generate the hash with random salt:

```
$hash = hash('sha256', $salt . $pw); //$pw is the cleaned user submitted password
```

When the user logs in, compare the stored hash using the stored randomly generated salt:

```
$loginHash = hash('sha256', $dbSalt . $pw);
if ($loginHash == $dbHash) {
    //Logged in
} else {
    //Failed
}
```

How does that look?

Comment: It should also be added that this is for a custom CMS system used by less than 10 people. Log-ins are not very frequent and a ban would be lifted quickly after a phone call to the individual

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, here's a few:

1. You shouldn't be using `md5` anymore.  You *can*, but there are better methods (Such as `sha512` used with the [`hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function).
2. I would use a MUCH longer static salt as well.  I suggest at least 64 characters (after all, it's minimal overhead to compute on write, but much more difficult to guess).
3. I would also add a dynamic (random) salt as well.  Generate a new one for each user, and store it along side the password hash (it's common to separate them by a `:` character).  This way, even if your static salt is compromised, a new rainbow table would need to be generated (or at least iterated against) for each password in your db...
4. Don't trust or operate based upon IP address for anything non-temporal.  Most ISPs use a form of NAT where more than one user will be seen from a single IP (and this will only become more prevalent with the exhaustion of the IPv4 namespace).  If you want to rate-limit or temporarily block IP addresses, fine.  But don't ban on them...
5. Your `clean()` function should either check for a string first, or force it to be a string: (`$str = is_string($str) ? trim($str) : (string) $str;`).  It doesn't prevent sql injection at all.  But the `stripslashes` call is necessary (exactly how you have it) to allow the code to work on servers that have `magic_quotes_gpc` set (which will attempt to escape quotes for you)...  So keep that around.
6. Format your code better.  Create functions to handle related tasks.  That way you don't have 75 lines of procedural code to look through to figure out what's going on.  Better yet, wrap it in a class and move the common tasks (db access, etc) into their own classes.  And remember to indent properly.  Readability is king, so don't take shortcuts...

**Edit:** As far as how to validate the password, you fetch the salted hash first, then re-compute the hash with the stored salt.  (The `makeSaltedHash` function I show below makes additional use of something called [Key Stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_strengthening).

```
function validatePassword($password, $hash) {
    list($oldHash, $salt) = explode(':', $hash, 2);
    $newHash = makeSaltedHash($password, $salt);
    return $hash == $newHash;
}

function makeSaltedHash($password, $salt = '') {
    if (empty($salt)) {
        $salt = makeRandomSalt(mt_rand(64, 128));
    }
    $hash = hash('sha512', $password . $salt . SALT);
    for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++) {
        $hash = hash('sha512', $password . $salt . SALT . $hash);
    }
    return $hash . ':' . $salt;
}

function makeRandomSalt($length = 64) {
    $salt = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $lenght; $i++) {
        $salt .= chr(mt_rand(33, 126));
    }
    return $salt;
}
```

Comment: So the salt is stored in the same column in the table as the password - salt:password? This is where I really get fuzzy, how to validate on log-in if the SALT is randomly generated when the user creates the account or changes their password.

Comment: @NightMICU: Yes, you can do that.  You could store it in a separate column, etc.  See my edit (I'm about to do it) for how to validate this kind of thing in pseudo code...

Comment: @NightMICU please note that most of these salt-related points are just bullshit. First of all nobody in the whole world would bother with these hashes. Nobody needs them.

Comment: @Col: please explain that to Gizmodo.  Sure, weak passwords will always be able to be defeated if you know the code used to generate them.  But if you don't know the exact details of the code, and you use a strong salting scheme, even something like `1234` should be quite hard to break even if your database is compromised.  But it will always make good passwords even harder to compromise even if they know the code.  So I don't see how it's possible that salting well can be (as you say) *bullshit*...  In fact, not salting well would be irresponsible...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Okay, just so I'm clear - all three functions in your edit are used to validate at log-in? Still trying to understand how it validates if it is generating something random

Comment: It's only generating something random when you first store the password (set or reset).  Every "verification" stage just reads the current value of the salt and re-computes the hash with that salt.  There's nothing random about it.  So, to set the password the first time, you'd call `makeSaltedHash($password)` which would make a new random salt.  But then whenever you call `validatePassword($password, $hash)`, it's just reading the old salt and using that (hence no randomness).  There is nothing random when verifying.  Only when creating new...  And that's the strong point about it.

Comment: @ircmaxell Ahh okay, thanks for clarifying that. So makeSaltedHash() and makeRandomSalt() are also unrelated? Is it a "use one or the other" thing or are both used to end up with the final product? I apologize for not following this too well.

Comment: Well, they are unrelated.  The only relation is that if you don't pass a salt to `makeSaltedHash`, it will call `makeRandomSalt` to generate one.  But otherwise there is no relation.  `makeRandomSalt` just returns a random string of the specified length.  `makeSaltedHash` takes a string and a salt (and generates the salt if it's empty) and returns you a salted hash.

Comment: Okay, when the user logs-in, which is passed to validatePassword() - the password from the log-in form or the password stored in the database? As my script stands now, the Salt is static and can easily be compared to the salted password on the table. I am sorry to be such a pain, but could you please provide an example of how this cross check would actually work? What values are passed to the function and how is the actual match accomplished? As I said before, I've found tutorials but they all seem to fall off a cliff when it gets to that subject.

Comment: The first param of `validatePassword` is `$password`, which means the plain text password that you want to validate (the user input).  The second parameter is `$hash` which is the stored hash from the db.  So just replace `$loginResult['password'] == $encryptedPassword` in your code with `validatePassword($password, $loginResult['password'])` (where `$password` comes from early on in the code).  Oh, and the code I provided also uses the static salt.  All this does is move the hash computation from before to after the DB query...  Otherwise the flow is the same.

Comment: Ah okay, the pieces are coming together. Need to take a break before I begin to implement this, might have some more questions later on today. Thanks so much for your helpful tips and patience!

Comment: @ircmaxell: I am still hopelessly lost on how to implement this, I would greatly appreciate it if you could give me a more detailed code explanation. Your makeRandomSalt function seems to output : as part of the salt, which makes it impossible to split the stored hash.

Comment: @NightMICU: pop over into the PHP StackOverflow chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Comment: @NightMICU: Ahh, now I see, I just edited the functions to swap the `salt` to the end of the string rather than the beginning...

Comment: @ircmaxell: Might not be the best out there but I think I may have found a solution using part of what you told me and some of what I found in a tutorial. Check my original post in a few minutes and let me know what you think. Also, mind if I scan your barcode?

Answer (score 4):

Two tips from me:

- Don't use stripslashes or magic quotes to prevent SQL injection. Use PDO parameters. No exceptions.
- Use a different salt for every user. The salt is no secret, store it in the DB along with the user record. Using the same salt for everyone makes your database more attackable.

Unrelated, but often overlooked: Do not limit password length for your users. I've seen too many web sites that impose an arbitrary limit (like 12 characters) on password length, but then have laughable complexity rules (*"at least one upper, one lower, a digit and a special character but not '<', '>'"* or such nonsense). This is very hostile, avoid it.

Comment: Good tips indeed. So should I just get rid of the clean() function since I am using PDO prepared statements? And yes, I agree with the password rules - that is something I do not practice.

Comment: @NightMICU: Don't remove the `clean` function unless you can control your server environment and turn off `magic_quotes_gpc`.  If you can't, you still need to have that function...

Answer (score 1):

1. You're using MD5, which isn't considered "safe" anymore.
2. You really need a longer salt.

For effectively using salting, please [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453769/is-this-using-pdo-and-prepared-statements-correctly-for-a-secure-login/4453814#4453814).

Comment: I figured the SALT would need to be longer, that one was for demo.. can you suggest a length? I'm guessing it is best practice to avoid dictionary words. As for MD5, should I use sha1() instead?

Comment: @NightMICU I updated my answer. In the referred question, look for the `hash()` function.

Comment: @Night Use ` hash('sha256',$yourstring); `. It's better than sha1

Comment: To be honest, I get a little bit confused when it comes to SALT and HASH. How does one validate a password upon log-in if the SALT is randomly assigned at the time of creation? That is what seems to be lacking from the tutorials I have come across on the subject. Obviously it being random is a plus when it comes to security but wouldn't it need to be matched in order to complete the log-in process?

Comment: +1, I thought your answer was helpful.. I don't know why there are so many downvotes going on here. I'm just thankful for advice

Comment: Thanks. I agree. Back to topic: you'll have to store the salt separately, which is a security issue again. The purpose of referring to the other question was to hint at PHP's `hash()` function to create digests using SHA256.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldnt ban - just put in a recaptcha after 2 failed attempts but if you really want to use memcache to store the ip. set( $ip, true, false, $secondsTTL ); later on you check with get( $ip ) - set the TTL to 2 hours. 
you might also want to put everything in functions and find out what you rather want to use for strings quote or double quote. ;)

all together it looks like it would work but its really hard to read and some stuff is redundant.

Comment: I agree with the ban under most cases, but this is a small CMS system that has about 10 accounts and I have contact information for all. The recaptcha isn't a bad idea, though.. wish I'd thought of that!

Answer (score -5):

In `clean()` you should add `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Depending on you server and other settings, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` can be empty.

I would recommend to create a simple redirect function to prevent errors when forgetting the `exit` after a `header()` redirect.

Example:

```
function redirect($url) {
  if (!headers_sent()) {
     header('Location: '.$url);
  } else {
     // echo $url;
  }
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I think stripslashes is a little outdated aswell.

Comment: By using bound parameters, escaping is done by PDO. `mysql_real_escape_string()` would add unneccessary slashes and only works, if a MySQL connection is established. -1

Comment: I should add that the original version did not use PDO prepared statements. Should the clean() function be removed in light of this upgrade? Perhaps redundant?

Comment: @NightMICU No; complex passwords containing quotes might still be escaped by the "magic" quotes.